# "Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt" despite grunt installed locally

Tags: node.js, npm, gruntjs

I ran the following commands:

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
npm install grunt --save-dev
```

And it still gives me this error!

Looking in the "node_modules", I see a "grunt" directory.

I also tried with "npm install -g grunt".

I also tried clearing the cache: "npm cache clean".

Nothing works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your node/npm up to date? very old versions are incompatible with modern grunt.

Comment: @mrEthol Yes. Node is version "v6.4.0" and npm is version "3.10.3"

Comment: did this ever get solved? this isn't working for me either. :/

Comment: @cora I had to use `sudo` to install it.